List of figures, appendices, spacing
How can I add spacing between figures of different chapters in my list of figures of the appendices? I tried several things which I found on this website, but nothing works.
Code:
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}  %This line imports the tocloft package, which provides extensive customization options for table of contents, list of figures, and list of tables.
%lijsten maken
\newcommand{\listappendixname}{Contents Appendices}
\newlistof{appendix}{loa}{\listappendixname}
\newcommand{\mylistfigurename}{List of Figures Appendices}
\newlistof{appfigure}{loaf}{\mylistfigurename}
\newcommand{\mylisttablename}{List of Tables Appendices}
\newlistof{apptable}{loat}{\mylisttablename}
\usepackage{xpatch}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\mylistfigurename}
%\addcontentsline{loaf}{\vspace{1.2cm}}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\appendix}{
\xpatchcmd{\ttl@addcontentsline}
{\addcontentsline{toc}}
{\addcontentsline{loa}}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\NR@chapter}
{\addcontentsline{loa}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}
{}{}
\renewcommand{\ext@figure}{loaf}
\renewcommand{\ext@table}{loat}

}

Depending on the document class, \chapter should add 10pt into the TOC, LOF and LOT automatically.

That is indeed the case for my list of figures and list of tables of my report. But I made a separate list for my list of figures and list of  tables of my appendices, and here, I do not have spacing between the chapters. I do not know how to do this.

\appendix should not change things, unless you stop using \chapter.  Try \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}} etc.
